# PHP 7.2: pcntl_fork does not exist as function

Tags: php, function, pcntl

On my macOS PHP 7.2.0RC1 from php-osx.liip.ch, the following code returns `false`:

```php
function_exists('pcntl_fork')
```

However, the PHP CLI from which the script is called, says that pcntl is enabled (`php -i`), and it is not on the list of `disabled_functions` either.

How could I make `pcntl_fork` usable?

Comment: What environment are you trying to run your script in -- are you using the PHP CLI (`/usr/bin/php script.php`), or are you running it from a web server?

Comment: > the PHP CLI from which the script is called

Comment: Sanity check... `extension_loaded('pcntl')` Or just try the fork function?

Comment: I'd verify the ini file is the cli one. Double check on the disabled list. Should expect them to be disabled on your web server's php configuration. check `php -m`?

Comment: `php -m` shows the pcntl module enabled.

Answer (score 0):

My script had the shebang set to `#!/usr/bin/php`, and that version is somehow different from `/usr/local/bin/php`.